# c# Get TextSelection on AvalonEdit.TextDocument

Tags: c#, wpf

I use the AvalonEdit.TextDocument control. Now I want to get the current text-selection/textmark from it. But the class implments no any convenient property or method.
How I can get the current text selection from AvalonEdit.TextDocument?

PS: It does not really make much sense here to add some code from my app

Comment: The `TextDocument` has no notion of a selection, it's just the document data. You can get the selection easily from the `TextEditor` (for a simple selection) or the `TextArea` (if you need full control over it, eg multiple selection segments etc).

Comment: Ok, many thanks! I did not know the AvalonEdit previously.

Comment: Well, I guess you should [read the docs](http://avalonedit.net/documentation/) then :)

Comment: Thanks!  By the way, the Editor.SelectedText-Property is allways empty :-(

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found to deal with selections with an AvalonEdit editor is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<SelectionSegment> selectionSegments = Editor.TextArea.Selection.Segments;
TextDocument document = Editor.TextArea.Document;
foreach (SelectionSegment segment in selectionSegments)
{
    //DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH THE SELECTIONS
    int lineStart = document.GetLineByOffset(segment.StartOffset).LineNumber;
    int lineEnd = document.GetLineByOffset(segment.EndOffset).LineNumber;
    for (int i = lineStart; i <= lineEnd; i++)
    {
        //Do something with each line in the selection segment
    }
}
```

In my case I needed to mark something on each line selected, so that's why I split it into lines.